# FactoryBot to build list of objects with trait

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I'm using factory_bot to create objects in my test, here is a example of my factory:

```
factory :user do
  name "John"
  surname "Doe"

  trait :with_photo do
    ignore do
      photo_count 1
    end

    after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
      FactoryBot.create_list(:photo, evaluator.photo_count)
    end
  end
end
```

So I can create a user with photo like:

```
FactoryBot.create(:user, :with_photo)
```

Or without photo :

```
FactoryBot.create(:user)
```

Or create a list of users :

```
FactoryBot.build_list(:user, 5)
```

But how can I build a list of users with trait (trait being `:with_photo`), if I wanted to create five of them with photo?

Note: FactoryBot was previously called FactoryGirl

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Doesn't this work? It should...

```
FactoryBot.build_list(:user, 5, :with_photo)
```

#### Reference

[FactoryBot - Building or Creating Multiple Records](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#building-or-creating-multiple-records)

Comment: it wasnt working for me either. Until I realized I was using the plural. `users`

Comment: It seems important to add the traits first after count, followed by specification of other attributes.
`FactoryGirl.build_list(:user, 5, :with_photo, tag: 'value')`
It would not work, if you add `:with_photo` after `tag:`

Answer (score 9):

You can also pass multiple traits to `create_list` and `build_list` example;

```rb
factory :user do
  name { "Friendly User" }

  trait :male do
    name { "John Doe" }
    gender { "Male" }
  end

  trait :admin do
    admin { true }
  end
end

# creates 3 admin users with gender "Male" and name "Jon Snow" using the admin and male trait
build_list(:user, 3, :admin, :male, name: "Jon Snow")
create_list(:user, 3, :admin, :male, name: "Jon Snow")
```

> Just make sure the traits comes after the number of records you wish to create, the last argument is a hash that would override the record attribute.

[More on traits on the official docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits)